# Join MSB and LSB of a 16 bit signed integer (two's complement)

Tags: c++, integer, twos-complement

I'm working with a proprietary protocol that transmits integers as 16 bit two's complement in two parts. The LSB is transmitted first followed by the MSB. Is the following code to restore the original value correct?

```
unsigned char message[BLK_SIZE];
// read LSB to message[0] and MSB to message[1]
short my_int = (message[1] << 8) | message[0];
```

Comment: Looks OK to me - what makes you think that it may not be correct ?

Comment: Yes, it looks OK. You should write a test for it, which will tell you if it is OK in the context of your specific application.

Comment: @Paul: Ah I should have mentioned that. I'm not sure because: 1) IIRC short isn't guaranteed to be 16bit. What happened if its 8 or 32? 2) operating on a unsigned char and assign it to a short works as expected?

Comment: @Neil: Unfortunately I'm not yet able to write a test because I've only the spec saying that's an 16 bit singed two's complement and that LSB is first.

Comment: short is guaranteed to be *at least* 16 bits. To guard against the (very rare) possibility of it being > 16 bits use the Posix types in <stdint.h> - this would be `int16_t` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that code will fail if `short` is not 16 bits, so your code may fail on some platforms. You may never find a platform it fails on though.

int16_t, if available on your target platform(s), may be a better choice.

Comment: Where does int16_t come from? Is that standard c++, c or some POSIX stuff?

Comment: I should have been more specific - I believe it would fail for negative values if short is *larger* than 16 bits, which is permitted by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but you could use intrinsic C functions for ensuring that your protocol is truly platform independant:

[`short my_int = ntohs(*(short*)message)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)

Comment: He wants a conversion specific to his own protocol.